# can't get time data via $_POST['attime']) to UPDATE mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I use https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker for setting time:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.clockpicker-with-callbacks').clockpicker({
        donetext: 'Done',
        afterDone: function() {

        $.post( "2_settime.php", { 
            attime : this.value
        })      

        }
    })
    .find('input').change(function(){
        console.log(this.value);
    });
if (/Mobile/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $('input').prop('readOnly', true);
}
</script>
```

And here is 2_settime.php, where goes the data:

```
<?
// Config file!
include "config.php";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbusr, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//param-vars

$attime=strval($_POST['attime']);
$attime=strval($_GET['attime']);
//$attime=$_POST['attime'];

//CHANGE STATUS

$conn->query("UPDATE 2dopuzzler SET attime = '$attime' WHERE ordernum = 123");

echo $attime;
?>
```

That's it. I can get my time written to mysql by this: `2_settime.php?attime=18:51`

**echo $attime;** -- *works*, but I can't get time from another php where is clockpicker. Please, help.

**UPDATE!**

To make sure it's correct I change the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.clockpicker-with-callbacks').clockpicker({
        donetext: 'Done',
        afterDone: function() {

        $.post( "2_settime.php", { 
            attime: this.value
        }).done(function( data, status ) {

         console.log('data: '+data+' status: '+status);

         if(data == 'success' && status == 'success'){      

         }else{

         }
      }
);


        }
    })
    .find('input').change(function(){
        console.log(this.value);
    });
if (/Mobile/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $('input').prop('readOnly', true);
}
</script>
```

So. I get in my console: `data:    status: success`

Comment: Nice code, now i understand where attime comes from... Why a second question ?

Comment: sorry, it was urgent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this part of your code:

```
$attime=strval($_POST['attime']);
$attime=strval($_GET['attime']);
```

What you do:

- First, you read the POST variable via `$_POST['attime']` into `$attime`.
- Then you write `$_GET['attime']` into the existing variable `$attime`.

As `$_GET['attime']` is not set in a post request, you'll loose the value saved in the first line.

A solution could be:

```
if(isset($_POST['attime'])) {
    $attime=strval($_POST['attime']);
} else if(isset($_GET['attime'])) {
    $attime=strval($_GET['attime']);
} else {
    //not sent
    $attime=null;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `$_REQUEST['attime']`. But then it's not clear whether the value comes via get or post

Comment: No, it's not a solution. I can remove `$attime=strval($_GET['attime']);` and it's nothing... I updated the question.